# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 - Android Build Error - Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

After I have updated my android sdk, I got this type of error when I try to create android build for my game.

[image]

At present, My game source code contains two plugins, one is Google Play Games and second is RevMob. Before it generated build correctly but at present it is getting above error.

Please give some explanation in this. Via google I got so much same forum questions in stack overflow but those are for core platforms. So can't able to decide how to apply them for unity.

At present my terminal java version display like this :

[image]

Comment: Usually this means that you are using a different java runtime version that the java version used for compilation.  
E.g. you compiled your code with java 7 and try to run it with java 8, or vice versa.

Comment: @YoavGur, how to solve this problem in mac system? This is big question for me. I can able to understand problem but how to sort this out?

Comment: What JDK version did you use to compile your code?

Comment: @YoavGur, Thanks for your reply but I just figure out solution.

Comment: @YoavGur Java 8 will happily run Java 7 compiled code.   The reverse is not true however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution by choose latest version of JDK selection in Unity.

[image]

I just changed Unity JDK path to latest installed version. Then it solved my build problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Add the variable as shown below.
Change to new version of your java ,for me is: jdk1.8.0_65
(make sure restart pc)
**good luck.:)**
[image]

Comment: I cleaned up a lot of my PATH and environmental variables but I think this was the solution. But make sure to restart Unity because it definitely didn't work until I did that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools
```

And then checking all the recommended options:

[image]